# Compile same file with different flags using CMAKE

Tags: g++, cmake

I want to compile the same .cpp source file into two different target executables and I am using cmake.  One will have some instrumentation code and the other won't.  That way I can compare the overhead of instrumentation.

I have the instrumentation code separated with #ifdefs so I want to define a value using the -D flag.  I see that is possible with

```
add_definitions(-DINSTRUMENT)
```

But it looks like this then applies to all the executables created in that directory. I'm wondering if there is a good way to set the definition only for a specific executable target.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set the [COMPILE_DEFINITIONS](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) property of one of the targets to have target-specific definitions:

```
set_target_properties (instrumented_target PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "INSTRUMENT")
```

**Update:**

Starting from CMake 2.8.11 you can also use [`target_compile_definitions`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_definitions.html) for the same purpose.

Comment: That property is also available on a per-source file basis, using "set_property(SOURCE source_file_name PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ...)"

Comment: @DLRdave, I think it should be noted that using `set_target_properties()` won't overwrite definitions already added by `add_definitions()` defined earlier. (I was worried about this until I ran `make VERBOSE=1`)