# How to compile the two set of source file separately using cmake?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am trying to generate coverage report using gcov and lcov from a c++ project.
Here is the cmake file [link](https://github.com/mtconnect/cppagent/blob/7e4fb88b689ad98676fe78f0aee9fcce402d68e3/test/CMakeLists.txt). Now the test_src has two types of files. One is the unit test files. and the other set is the actual application source files. Now what i want is to compile only the application source files with an additional `--coverage` flag and not the other unit test files. Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

My failed attempt 1:

`set_property(SOURCE [../agent/adapter.cpp [../agent/agent.cpp [../agent/checkpoint.cpp [../agent/component.cpp [../agent/component_event.cpp [../agent/change_observer.cpp [../agent/connector.cpp [../agent/cutting_tool.cpp [../agent/data_item.cpp 
[../agent/device.cpp [../agent/globals.cpp [../agent/options.cpp [../agent/xml_parser.cpp [../agent/xml_printer.cpp [../agent/config.cpp [../agent/service.cpp [../agent/ref_counted.cpp [../agent/asset.cpp [../agent/version.cpp [../agent/rolling_file_logger.cpp]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]] PROPERTY [${GCOV_COMPILE_FLAGS}])`

My failed attempt 2:

`set_property(SOURCE ../agent/*.cpp
 PROPERTY [${GCOV_COMPILE_FLAGS}])`

Also i tried without those brackets.

Heres the [official Doc:](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_property.html)

What am i Missing?

**UPDATE2**

`file(GLOB AGENT_SOURCES ../agent/*.cpp)
set_property(SOURCE AGENT_SOURCES
 PROPERTY ${GCOV_COMPILE_FLAGS})`

did not work. tried removing these files from test_srcs but it caused error.

**MY FILE**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6) 

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../agent/CMake;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)
set(CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK NEVER FORCE)
set(CMAKE_FIND_APPBUNDLE NEVER)

set(GCOV_COMPILE_FLAGS  "-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -r")
set(GCOV_LINK_FLAGS "-lgcov")
if(WIN32)
  set(LibXML2_INCLUDE_DIRS ../win32/libxml2-2.9/include )

  if(CMAKE_CL_64)
    set(bits 64)
  else(CMAKE_CL_64)
    set(bits 32)
  endif(CMAKE_CL_64)

  file(GLOB LibXML2_LIBRARIES "../win32/libxml2-2.9/lib/libxml2_a_v120_${bits}.lib")
  file(GLOB LibXML2_DEBUG_LIBRARIES ../win32/libxml2-2.9/lib/libxml2d_a_v120_${bits}.lib)

  set(CPPUNIT_INCLUDE_DIR ../win32/cppunit-1.12.1/include)
  file(GLOB CPPUNIT_LIBRARY ../win32/cppunit-1.12.1/lib/cppunitd_v120_a.lib)
endif(WIN32)

if(UNIX)
  execute_process(COMMAND uname OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME)
  if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES Linux)
    set(LINUX_LIBRARIES pthread)
  endif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES Linux)
endif(UNIX)

project (test)

set(test_srcs test.cpp
           adapter_test.cpp
           agent_test.cpp
           checkpoint_test.cpp
           config_test.cpp
           component_test.cpp
           component_event_test.cpp
           connector_test.cpp
           data_item_test.cpp
           device_test.cpp
           globals_test.cpp
           xml_parser_test.cpp
           test_globals.cpp
           xml_printer_test.cpp
           asset_test.cpp
           change_observer_test.cpp
           cutting_tool_test.cpp
           )

file(GLOB test_headers *.hpp ../agent/*.hpp)

include_directories(../lib ../agent .)

find_package(CppUnit REQUIRED)
find_package(LibXML2 REQUIRED)


add_definitions(-DDLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT ${LibXML2_DEFINITIONS})

set(AGENT_SOURCES ../agent/adapter.cpp 
           ../agent/agent.cpp 
           ../agent/checkpoint.cpp
           ../agent/component.cpp 
           ../agent/component_event.cpp 
           ../agent/change_observer.cpp
           ../agent/connector.cpp
           ../agent/cutting_tool.cpp
           ../agent/data_item.cpp 
           ../agent/device.cpp 
           ../agent/globals.cpp 
           ../agent/options.cpp
           ../agent/xml_parser.cpp 
           ../agent/xml_printer.cpp
           ../agent/config.cpp
           ../agent/service.cpp
           ../agent/ref_counted.cpp
           ../agent/asset.cpp
           ../agent/version.cpp
           ../agent/rolling_file_logger.cpp)

set_property(SOURCE ${AGENT_SOURCES}
 PROPERTY ${GCOV_COMPILE_FLAGS})

include_directories(${LibXML2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CPPUNIT_INCLUDE_DIR})

if(WIN32)
  set(WINVER "0x0501" CACHE STRING "Win32 API Target version (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)")
  add_definitions("/DWINVER=${WINVER}" "/D_WIN32_WINNT=${WINVER}")

  foreach(flag_var  
          CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
          CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO)
     if(${flag_var} MATCHES "/MD")
        string(REGEX REPLACE "/MD[d]?" "/MTd" ${flag_var} "${${flag_var}}")
     endif(${flag_var} MATCHES "/MD")
  endforeach(flag_var)
endif(WIN32)

add_executable(agent_test ${test_srcs} ${AGENT_SOURCES} ${test_headers})
target_link_libraries(agent_test ${LibXML2_LIBRARIES} ${CPPUNIT_LIBRARY} ${LINUX_LIBRARIES} ${GCOV_LINK_FLAGS})  
set_target_properties(agent_test PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD_RELEASE 1)`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile same file with different flags using CMAKE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843926/compile-same-file-with-different-flags-using-cmake)

Comment: @EtanReisner: This is not duplicate.The link you gave says it has two different targets and so he has different flags attached to the different targets. I have a single target.

Comment: See the comment about attaching the flags to source files too.

Comment: Hi @EtanReisner, yes the comment was relevant. But not working. Do i need to add the source files one by one? and do i need to remove those files from test_src?

Comment: I don't know any more than what that comment says (I don't use cmake). I'd look at the linked docs since clearly this is something that should, in theory, work. Assuming I understand your goal and the answer I linked to.

Comment: @EtanReisner: i Checked the docs before asking in here. I tried following docs. Sadly it didn't work.

Comment: Including what you tried and how it didn't work in the post is likely helpful to someone who actually knows cmake. And if nothing else it gives someone who doesn't (like me) a place to start looking to see what you might have missed/done wrong.

Comment: You certainly do not want to use brackets. How did it fail without brackets?

Comment: I do not believe you can use a wildcard for your source in the set_property command. However you can use file globbing to get the source file list into a cmake variable.

Comment: Look at the FILE(GLOB command for globbing. http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html

Comment: @drescherjm: Basically the files did compile but without the gcov flags. So no .gcno files were created. will try FILE(GLOB command ) and let you know.

Comment: @drescherjm: Also do i need to remove those files from the test_srcs list?

Comment: You need to post what you tried and what did not work. And how it failed. It's very hard to help when I can not see what is happening on your end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68763/discussion-between-codename-subho-and-drescherjm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call to set_property you are missing the PROPERTY name. You have only the value you want to attach to the property.

I believe you want COMPILE_FLAGS as the property name.

```
set_property(SOURCE ${AGENT_SOURCES} PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS ${GCOV_COMPILE_FLAGS})
```

In addition to this change you probably want to append as well since you are adding compile flags not replacing the defaults.

```
set_property(SOURCE ${AGENT_SOURCES} APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS ${GCOV_COMPILE_FLAGS})
```